# SQL request return nothing

Tags: sql

I try to get all row from a parkplaces table + the username row from users table.
All results must have status (from parkplaces table) row equal to 'current'.
Results must be sort by order asc.

Here is my request:

```
  SELECT parkplaces.*, users.username
    FROM parkplaces INNER JOIN users ON parkplaces.id_user = users.id
   WHERE status = 'current'
ORDER BY parkplaces.id ASC
```

When I try, the request return nothing.

What's wrong please, im little confused.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there's no data matching the query?

Comment: Check that status is not in uppercase, ie CURRENT

Comment: Yes there is...

Comment: Can you please post the results from the following: SELECT COUNT (*) FROM users u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM parkplaces p WHERE p.id_user = u.id)

Comment: Also, can you post the results from the following: SELECT status, COUNT (*) FROM users u GROUP BY status

Comment: Thanks Roberto, request work with LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see, you are trying to get `admin.username`

But the table is "users"? Should it be:

```
SELECT parkplaces.*, users.username 
FROM parkplaces
```

Comment: Sorry just an error in answer. My request well LECT parkplaces.*, users.username FROM parkplaces, but nothing :(

Comment: I would check two things, 1) check if the status is not in both tables (if both table got the status field, should get an error), and 2) manually check there is at least 2 ID matching (the ON condition) and with the status you want, can you confirm that at least one row should be returned? you can try the same query without the "Status" condition and see the result.

Comment: 1) Status is only present on the parkplaces table.
2) Everything seems to be ok but with a request without "status" condition, i got only one result instead all the entire parkplaces table... Weird...

Comment: try LEFT JOIN if you want ALL parkplaces (even if got not match on the users table)

Comment: LEFT JOIN work! Thanks. But now i need to understant what is the difference between LEFT and INNER. im gonna check the doc. Thanks a lot.